# The length of the curve $ =\dfrac{3}{4}x^{\frac{4}{3}}-\dfrac{3}{8}x^{\frac{2}{3}}+7$ from $x=1$ to $x=8$ equals.

Tags: integration, derivatives

The length of the curve $ =\dfrac{3}{4}x^{\frac{4}{3}}-\dfrac{3}{8}x^{\frac{2}{3}}+7$ from $x=1$ to $x=8$ equals.

$(A)=\ \dfrac{99}{8} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (B)=\dfrac{117}{8} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (C)=\dfrac{99}{4} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (D)=\dfrac{117}{4}$

$\int_{1}^{8}\sqrt{1+(y')^2}dx$

$y'=x^{\frac{1}{3}}-\frac{1}{4}x^{\frac{-1}{3}}$

$(y')^2=(x^{\frac{1}{3}}-\frac{1}{4}x^{\frac{-1}{3}})^2=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+x^{\frac{2}{3}}+\frac{x^{\frac{-2}{3}}}{16}}$

$\int_{1}^{8}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+x^{\frac{2}{3}}+\frac{x^{\frac{-2}{3}}}{16}}dx$

Which is hard to compute for the exam I am preparing for. This question came for $2$ marks(short type questions) and there is something I missing. Help me here finding the solution.

Comment: Your derivative and substituting into the integral seems to be all correct, maybe try the substitution $u=x^{1/3}$

Comment: @HenryLee Are your sure there is no other way? Then I am in peace with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u=x^{1/3}\Rightarrow du=\frac13x^{-2/3}dx\therefore dx=3x^{2/3}du=3u^2du$$
and so:
$$\sqrt{\frac12+x^{2/3}+\frac1{16}x^{-2/3}}dx\Rightarrow3\sqrt{\frac12+u^2+\frac1{16}u^{-2}}u^2du$$
then actually you could make the substitution:
$$v=u^2\Rightarrow du=\frac{dv}{2u}\therefore u^2du=\frac{udv}{2}=\sqrt{v}\frac{dv}{2}$$
now sub in:
$$\frac32\sqrt{\frac12+v+\frac1{16}v^{-1}}\sqrt{v}dv=\frac32\sqrt{v^2+\frac v2+\frac1{16}}dv$$
now take out the factor of $16$ so:
$$\frac38\sqrt{16v^2+8v+1}dv$$

---

If we try and factor this we get:
$$16v^2+8v+1=(4v+1)^2$$
and now your integral is simply:
$$\frac38\int_1^4(4v+1)dv$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Whenever you have positive and negative exponents, factor out the negative exponent. I'm also factoring out the fractions so we could see a perfect square a bit more easily.

$\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+x^{\frac{2}{3}}+\frac{x^\frac{-2}{3}}{16}}=\sqrt{\frac{x^{\frac{-2}{3}}}{16}}\sqrt{8x^{\frac{2}{3}}+16x^{\frac{4}{3}}+1}$

Taking the square root of $\frac{x^{\frac{-2}{3}}}{16}$ is easy. And for the other square root, try factoring $16y^2+8y+1$, where we have $y=x^{\frac{2}{3}}$ here.

Answer (score 1):

It is not hard to compute:
$$\sqrt{1+(y')^2} = \sqrt{1+x^{\frac{2}{3}}+\frac{x^{\frac{-2}{3}}}{16}-\frac{1}{2}} = \sqrt{x^{\frac{2}{3}}+\frac{x^{\frac{-2}{3}}}{16}+\frac{1}{2}} = \sqrt{(x^{\frac{1}{3}}+\frac{1}{4}x^{\frac{-1}{3}})^2} = x^{\frac{1}{3}}+\frac{1}{4}x^{\frac{-1}{3}}$$ Integral is easy to calculate now (just power rule).